# OpenCV C# Create Rectangle from extreme points

Tags: c#, opencv, rectangles, detect

I'm still working on my first alghorithm to detect objects on simple image.
After few operations, my normal image looks like below one.
Part of images have normal, one big 'skeleton' It's all about threadshold. But when my first object is detected well, second one fails.
For solve this problem, I want to get Big rectangle from this picture. Are there any possibilities to find extreme points? Green one's on the image.

With these points I would like to create Rectangle.

Of course the next step to improve my code will be make better contour of object :)

Do you have any tips to do that?
Maybe others solutions?

[image: Skeleton of image :)]

Comment: Just do contour detection on the binary image and then find the [`BoundingRectangle()`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/452e1258-fe52-aa28-cd4c-8465d727f026.htm)

Comment: I'm doing that and it finding a lot of small rectangles.